# which principles govern energy transformation?

Tags: energy

Can you point me please to the scientific principles that govern energy transformation? For example why we can't achive 100% harvesting from the various energy sources? I need the relevant theorems, principles etc.

Comment: That would be the first, second and third law of thermodynamics. The main takeaway is that conversion of other forms of energy into heat is not fully reversible.

Comment: Do these also explain why for example we have voltage loss across a cable? Or why our photovoltaics achive 40% efficiency? Do these principles apply to every case?

Comment: Yes, they apply to every case. One can make cables without voltage loss by using superconductors, but that's not a conversion process. The limit of terrestrial photovoltaic efficiency is given by the Carnot efficiency between a heat source of approx. 5800K and a heat sink of approx. 300K temperature. The result is on the order of 96%. We can currently achieve approx. 60% of that limit, if we really want to, but economically technology that is less efficient is still preferable. There is no reason why we couldn't do much better in the future (and we will).

Answer (score 1):

Principle of conservation of energy and second law of thermodynamics. Those apply in every imaginable case. One of the formulations of it gives a limit on how efficient a heat engine can be:

> A Carnot engine operated in this way is the most efficient possible heat engine using those two temperatures.

The efficiency of Carnot engine operating between $T_c$ and $T_h$ is given by $$ \eta = 1 - {T_c \over T_h}$$
However usually we are not even close to achieving this efficiency limit. 
The statement talks about **heat** engines, so you might think this is irrelevant. But effectively when extracting energy from our sources we are actually using heat engines. We use some sort of source of energy to heat up a reservoir and then use a turbine to generate electrical energy. So yes, there is a limit but usually the practicalities of building such an engine lead to a far lower efficiency (heat loos, friction, resistance and so on and so forth). You might say then "But this does not apply to solar cells!". But it does. In a photo-voltaic cell the heat source is the sun. So you can not be more efficient then a Carnot engine operating between the sun and Earth. Wikipedia claims that such an engine would be 95% efficient. But again there come in some other effects and subtleties that limit the efficiency (not all photons produce a electron-hole pair).

Answering the other point mentioned in the question: zero electrical resistance is possible, it is called superconductivity and is often used to minimise losses when a wire is carrying a very high current.